# Group By with Sum in nhibernate c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

My query consists of knowing the `NumCarroId`, `TotalGasto` and `VlrUnit`, in Sql I was able to do this but when I play in HQL, Apply GROUP BY next to SUM to make a ToList, to show me a list already added, but there are lots of errors:

I tried some examples but none worked, mostly I get the NullReference error, so I do not know how to implement GroupBy in project

> string hql = "select a.NumCarro.Id, sum(a.TotalGasto) gastos from Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido Between :dataInicial AND :dataFinal GROUP BY a.NumCarro.Id";

HQL Code:

```
public IList<Abastecimento> Resumo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal)
{
    string hql = "SELECT NumCarroId, DtAbastecido FROM Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido Between :dataInicial AND :dataFinal GROUP BY a.NumCarroId";
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
    .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
    .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal);
    return query.List<Abastecimento>();
}
```

My Table Abastecimento:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Abastecimento] (
[Id]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[DtAbastecido]  DATETIME        NULL,
[Litro]         INT             NULL,
[VlrUnit]       DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
[TotalGasto]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
[AutorId]       INT             NULL,
[NumCarroId]    INT             NULL,
[Km]            INT             NULL,
[NomeProdutoId] INT             NULL,
[Km_Andado]     INT             NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK84286500787E6DCB] FOREIGN KEY ([AutorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Usuario] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK842865002F58EAD8] FOREIGN KEY ([NumCarroId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Veiculo] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK8428650023D2F9D9] FOREIGN KEY ([NomeProdutoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Compra] ([Id])
```

);

My AbastecimentoController:

```
public ActionResult AbastecimentoResumo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal, int? pagina, Boolean? gerarPDF, AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
    {

        ViewBag.dataInicio = dataInicio;
        ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFinal;

        if (gerarPDF != true)
        {
            //Definindo a paginação
            int paginaQdteRegistros = 30;
            int paginaNumeroNavegacao = (pagina ?? 1);
            return View(abastecimento.ToPagedList(paginaNumeroNavegacao, paginaQdteRegistros));
        }
        else
        {
            int paginaNumero = 1;
            var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
            {

                ViewName = "TesteRelatorio",
                PageSize = Size.A4,
                IsGrayScale = true,
                Model = abastecimento.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, abastecimento.Count),
                PageMargins = new Margins { Bottom = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5, Top = 5 },

            };
            return pdf;
        }
    }
```

Abastecimento Model:

```
public class Abastecimento
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual int Litro { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DtAbastecido { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal VlrUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalGasto { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km_Andado { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Compra NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public virtual Veiculo NumCarro { get; set; }
}
```

Im try make this example:

```
 public ActionResult AbastecimentoResumo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal, int? pagina, Boolean? gerarPDF, AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
    {

        var data = ckm.Resumo(dataInicio, dataFinal).ToList();
        IList<Abastecimento> abastecimento = data.OrderBy(a => a.NumCarro.NCarro).ToList();

        var results = data.GroupBy(p => p.Id, p => p.NumCarro.NCarro).ToList();


}
```

And return me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento]'.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The query you'be quoted and the query in the code sample don't match. The query in the code sample will error as the second column in the select isn't grouped or aggregated.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Abastecimento` class?

Comment: edited question and add Abastecimento Model

Comment: @DavidOsborne sorry, it was an attempt I tried to make by the controller, but there was a failure, in that attempt I tried to do an ilist and apply the group by then and it returned the error of NullReference, but if I took out GroupBy it works normal bringing me all the data, which I do not need because I only want each NumCarroId applying the SUM in the Litro, and SUM in TotalGasto

Comment: Sure. You're not going to be able to project the results of that query into an `IEnumerable<Abastecimento>` as the query result contains two columns. Your going to have to project into an anonymous type or `Tuple<int, int>` or something similar.

Comment: I wanted you to bring the NumCarroid, Litro with SUM, Totalgasto with SUM, AutorId, to show who supplied and I ready, I am also trying to implement that brings me the lowest Km registered with the highest Km of that vehicle (NumCarroId), so I can make an average of spending in that period that I define using Between

Answer (score 0):

Can you use LINQ instead of HQL? You could then use something like:

```
var results = 
    session
        .Query<Abastecimento>()
        .Where(a => a.DtAbastecido <= dataFinal && a.DtAbastecido >= dataInicio)
        .GroupBy(a => a.NumCarro.Id)
        .Select(g => 
            new 
            {
                NumCarroId = g.Key, 
                Litri = g.Sum(a => a.Litro)
            })
        .ToList();
```

This projects into an anonymous type that might not be useful, but you could use another data structure to suit.

HQL seems a bit anachronistic, IMHO.

Comment: I'm going to apply it to my code, see if it works or if there is an error, and informs, in regards to applying in LINQ I'm importing it into the project

Comment: It is giving error when calling the Session.Query <Abastecimento>

Comment: error System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento]'.